# Is there an atomic_add() function on android

Tags: android

i need atomic addition on android, but i can't find  it . In asm/atomic.h file, it just have 
only ATOMIC_INIT(i) macro definition .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write code in C/C++ then you can use the GNU compiler [builtins for atomic ops](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)

Comment: tbh I haven't used them with the ndk, google has stripped a lot of thing from the toolchain - probably the atomic builtins as well. Have you tried with the crystax ndk? which version of the ndk do you use, r6?

Comment: grepping the toolchain shows they are available in the arm-7 compilers and used in the cxx-stl code in that toolchain:

sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/atomic_2.h:192:    { return __sync_add_and_fetch(&_M_i, __d); }

that is operator+=() of struct atomic_address

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you mean that you need this in native code, but if you don't, then I'd point out `AtomicInteger` from Java / Android libraries provides [addAndGet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#addAndGet%28int%29).

Comment: Hi Sean Owen,i use c++. And i think if it is in native code , it should remove the atomic.h file. I use __sync_add_and_fetch this build-in function. It point out it's undefined when linking